# visual basic 2005 & mySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, .net-2.0

do u need to download something for VB2005 to connect to a mySQL db?
cant connect to mysql db?
any suggestions?

Comment: There is no such animal as vb2005. Please pay attention to the tag prompts when creating your question.  Correct tagging is how people will find and answer your question.

Comment: apologies -> im not an expert with tags an dat

Comment: @Joel: I disagree with that opinion. Notwithstanding the no. of posts tagged as such on SO, "VB 2005" is a commonly used term in the developer community, Microsoft based forums and even titles for books based on this particular version of Visual Basic. However, your comment is wise in respect of a question on SO getting more exposure when it has one of the popular tags.

Answer (score 4):

You need library for working with MySQL

[MySQL Connector/NET](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)

Answer (score 0):

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

Great site for all sorts of connection strings...[http://www.connectionstrings.com/](http:///www.connectionstrings.com/)